# Repository pattern: isn't getting the entire domain object bad behavior (read method)?

Tags: repository-pattern, repository-design

A repository pattern is there to abstract away the actual data source and I do see a lot of benefits in that, but a repository should not use IQueryable to prevent leaking DB information and it should always return domain objects, not DTO's or POCO's, and it is this last thing I have trouble with getting my head around.

If a repository pattern always has to return a domain object, doesn't that mean it fetches way too much data most of the times? Lets say it returns an employee domain object with forty properties and in the service and view layers consuming that object only five of those properties are actually used.

It means the database has fetched a lot of unnecessary data a pumped that across the network. Doing that with one object is hardly noticeable, but if millions of records are pushed across that way and a lot of of the data is thrown away every time, is that not considered bad behavior?

Yes, when adding or editing or deleting the object, you will use the entire object, but reading the entire object and pushing it to another layer which uses only a fraction of it is not utilizing the underline database and network in the most optimal way. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing preventing you from having a separate read model (which could a separately stored projection of the domain or a query-time projection) and separating out the command and query concerns - CQRS.

If you then put something like GraphQL in front of your read side then the consumer can decide exactly what data they want from the full model down to individual field/property level.

Your commands still interact with the full domain model as before (except where it's a performance no-brainer to use set based operations).